Why my env variables are not availble when I try to use like process.env.varname
Below is my job setup I want all these to be available in website to connect to firebase. But when I try to use variables with process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY_DEV it's always empty string
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_dev:
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up environment variables for build (Dev)
        run: |
          echo "REACT_APP_ENV=development" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "REACT_APP_TEST_KEY=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_TEST_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "REACT_APP_BACKEND_END_POINT=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_BACKEND_END_POINT_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        env:
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY_DEV }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN_DEV }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_DEV }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_DEV }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID_DEV }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID_DEV }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID_DEV }}
          REACT_APP_BACKEND_END_POINT: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_BACKEND_END_POINT_DEV }}
          GENERATE_SOURCEMAP: false

      - name: Install dependencies and build
        run: |
          yarn install
          yarn build

      - name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting (Dev)
        uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          firebaseServiceAccount: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_AIP_DEV }}
          channelId: dev-${{ github.sha }}
          projectId: aip-dev

EDIT - Below works fine but it can only access the repo secrets not environmet secrets
- name: Install dependencies and build
        env:
          REACT_APP_ENV: production
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY_LIVE  }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN_LIVE  }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_LIVE  }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_LIVE  }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID_LIVE  }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID_LIVE  }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID_LIVE  }}
          REACT_APP_BACKEND_END_POINT: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_BACKEND_END_POINT_LIVE }}
          GENERATE_SOURCEMAP: false
        run: |
          yarn install
          yarn build


Each step in a Cloud Build build config is run in its own process. Setting environment variables in one step, defines them in that step (process) only. If you want environment variables to be available in the step that includes yarn build, then you must define them in that step.

Repositry secerts works but environment secrets don't
